# show loading image while server process the request

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to know if it is possible to have some thing on the browser while the page is loading. for example if i am on the home page and i click the about us page the browser will send an http request to server and the server will process the request and perform required  operation and send back the about us page to client (browser). Now suppose this whole procedure takes 2-3 secs and the browser window stays blank for that time. so i want to know if it is possible to have something like a loading image on the page while the server is processing the request.

I know  it can be doen using jquery and ajax but i am looking for any other option.

i am using codeigniter framework for php.

Comment: AJAX is only one option to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion guys but as I said I don't want to use jQuery or ajax for security purposes...

Anyways I found out answer to my own question. It can be done using output buffering control of Php. We need to just echo what you want in output then just flush the data to browser. In this way the browser starts receiving output even when the server is processing the request.

This example can explains it:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );   //this tells browser that its html
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ ) //loop to process
{
    echo $i . '<br />'; //display current value
    flush();            //flush buffer data to browser
    ob_flush();         //flush buffer data to browser
    sleep(1);           //wait for 1 second
}
echo 'End ...<br />';

?>
```

Comment: nice, i will check it out as well.

Comment: Hi..Angry Coder how you used above code to show loading image